# Axis limits and labels in vtk cubeAxesActor

Tags: python, c++, visualization, vtk

Is there a way to change the labels of the axis easily in `cubeAxesActor` in `vtk`. In order to fit the data to the screen I had to scale it to roughly [-1:1] in each direction. But then I can't find a way to change the labels of the axis to, say [-1000:1000]. Here is an example, 
[image]

I'd like the vertical axis to be from -1000 to 1000 and not from -3.0 to 3.0. Is there a way of doing it without changing each of the numbers one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SetBounds` method from `cubeAxesActor` class to specify the region in space around which to draw the bounds.

For instance, if you use the method like this:

```
cubeAxesActor.SetBounds(-1, 1,-1000, 1000,-1, 1)
```

The bounds in x-axis and z-axis remain from [-1,1], but the y-axis is set to interval [-1000,1000] as you wanted. [image]

Above is an example in which the method is used with the following arguments:

```
cubeAxesActor.SetBounds(-10, 1,-1, 1,-1, 1)
```

Hope it helps!